# Smallest odd number n such that $2^n-1$ is divided by twin primes.

Tags: number-theory

This is a problem from Elementary Number Theory by Burton (7th ed.)
I am finding the smallest odd number n such that $2^n-1$ is divided by twin primes $p$ and $q$, where $3 < p < q$.

I followed a hint from the book, and result are $p \equiv -1\pmod {24}$ and $q \equiv 1\pmod {24}$. Now, how can I solve this?

Comment: So the answer is $p=71$, $q=73$?

Comment: The answer would be $n$, @GregoryGrant

Comment: I'm confused... obviously

Comment: I know that that's right answer but I don't know the way to solve. (from solution)

Comment: You asked for $n$ but gave the result as $p$ and $q$, so I'm confused...

Comment: @GregoryGrant No, he stated a conclusion about $p,q$. (The conclusion is the "result" of applying the hint.) That doesn't mean $p,q$ is the answer.

Comment: Is that a sufficient condition on $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Sorry for confunsion. the answer is $n=315$, where $p=71$, $q=73$.

Comment: @Terry: and how many grains of rice requires the Calif of the origins of chess to have $2 ^{315}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first pair of twin primes $\equiv \pm 1\pmod{24}$ is $p=71$, $q=73$. One checks that $2^n\equiv \pmod p\iff 35\mid m$ and $2^n\equiv \pmod q\iff 9\mid m$. This would yield $\color{red}{n=315}$ as candidate.

The next suitable twin primes would be $192\pm 1$. Here the orders of $2$ are $95$ and $96$, thus yielding much larger $n$.
The next suitable twins are $312\pm1$.

We suspect that $315$ is indeed minimal and can work downwards from there. As we are only interested in twin primes $>2^8$, crude factorizations of $2^n-1$ would often suffice to show that no twins occur. (Contrary to this bold statement, I am however having difficulties at first glance to exclude that $2^{313}-1$ has some quite large twin prime factors). [In fact $2^{313}-1$ doesn't; it is the product of 4 primes whose differences are not small.]

Answer (score 1):

You have $p=24k-1, q=24k+1$.  I would just start looking at twin primes of that form.  For $k=3$, we get $p=71, q=73$, which are both prime, so we would need $2^n-1$ to be divisible by $5183=71\cdot 73$  We know that if $n=ab$, $2^n-1$ is divisible by both $2^a-1$ and $2^b-1$, so we can look for the first $2^a-1$ divisible by $71$ and $2^b-1$ divisible by $73$.  A brute force search says $a=35, b=9$, so $n=315$ works.  To prove this is minimal, you would have to show that there is not a higher twin prime pair that divides a lower $2^n-1$.  The easiest way is just to factor all the smaller $2^n-1$s and look.

Comment: I'm still having fun trying to factor $2^{313}-1$ :)

Comment: @Hagen  By hand? Can by any chance to help the chaine 313a + (2-1) = 311b + ($2^3$ - 1) = 307c + ($2^7$ - 1) = 293d + ($2^{20}$ - 1) an so on descending the sequence of primes less than 313?. I don't know and it may be that you are using this. I like the two answers, yours and Ross's.